# On differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider the integral: $I$= $\int_2^{\infty} f(x)g(x) \mathrm{d}x $, where $f(x)$ and$g(x)$ are nonconstant functions. Assuming that this integral exists, does this necessarily mean that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable functions of $x$ ?

Personally, i think the answer is yes, since we can't evaluate $I$ by integrating by parts *without* differentiating  $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Who says that the integral can be evaluated via integration by parts?

Answer (score 2):

No. There are lots of ways to make the product integrable even when integration by parts won't help.

$f$ might be $0$ throughout an interval where $g$ is nasty.

Or both $f$ and $g$ could be piecewise linear functions oscillating back and forth between the $x$-axis and $y=1/x^2$ (sawtooth functions).

Comment: He said they are nonconstant functions. I interpret this as not even locally constant. This excludes the case where $f \equiv 0$ for some interval.

Comment: @MarkFantini added another counterexample ...

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the function $p(x):=f(x)\>g(x)$ is (say: Riemann) integrable over any interval $[0,b]$, $b>0$, and that  $J(b):=\int_0^b p(x)\>dx$  has a finite limit when $b\to\infty$.